# Change keyboard shortcut for hard refresh in Google Chrome for macOS

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut

I'm used to using <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh a webpage in browser. On  Mac, I found a way to change the keyboard shortcut for refreshing. Under System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → App Shortcuts, I added Google Chrome.app with the Menu Title set to `Reload This Page` and the Keyboard Shortcut set to <kbd>F5</kbd>.

This all went very well, however I would also like to be able to do a hard reload by using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. I have googled for ages but unable to find a working Menu Title for hard refresh.

Does anyone know how to change the keyboard shortcut for a hard reload, or what the Menu Title for it is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Menu Title for hard reload in Google Chrome for macOS is `Force Reload This Page` with the default keyboard shortcut set to: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>. The Menu Title is revealed when the said key combination are depressed or when you search for matching title under Google Chrome Menu → Help → Search. (as user will not be initially aware of the shortcut.)

#### Menu Title revealed on key depression:

[image]

#### Menu Title revealed on searching:

[image]

When setting the keyboard shortcut, set Menu Title as: `Force Reload This Page` and register <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> as the intended keyboard shortcut.

#### Reload This Page:

[image]

#### Force Reload This Page:

[image]

#### Keyboard shortcuts after assignment:

[image]